# home dashboard in obi

Tags: oracle, obiee

I am using OBI 11g and I want to change the home page/dashboard. Although I want to insert in the new home-dashboard some things we have in the default home-dashboard like the "recently accessed" reports.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to edit the dashboard, and place reports on it?

Comment: I mean make a new dashboard, but add the block "recently accessed reports" That is now available on the default dashboard. But if i van edit the default home page from analytics it is also ok

Comment: Do you have access to edit? There should be an edit dashboard option in the page options dropdown, to the right hand side below your sign in name.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an "edit dashboard" option in the top right corner. Check if you have access to it. Now after editing you can move the contents from catalog to the dashboard. Now save and run the dashboard.